# Weird data in VCF file

Tags: vcf, snp, gatk, haplotypes, vcftools

I am using GATK HaploTypeCaller for SNP calling. I have 300 samples. As far as I understand that if a sample is missing a SNP it should be denoted by ./., however, I am getting a lot of values like 0/0:0,0:0:0:0,0,0.

As a result it is considered as homozygous and downstream processing detecting no missing data at all, like when I am using vcftools. This is weird as my sequencing coverage is only 1.0X, so I should have a lot of missing data per SNP. What is going wrong here? Is it okay if I convert all the `0/0:0,0:0:0:0,0,0 values to ./.:.,.:.:.:.,.,.`

The commands I used:

```
gatk HaplotypeCaller 
    -I P1_q10_sorted_rg_dedup.bam 
    -R Zm-B73-REFERENCE-NAM-5.0.fa 
    -ERC GVCF 
    -O P1.g.vcf
```

```
gatk GenomicsDBImport \
    -V P1.g.vcf 
    --genomicsdb-workspace-path /fs/project/PMIU0157/Mahmood_Hasan/Second/vcf_files/database/mop1/mop1_db_chr1 
    --intervals chr1
```

```
gatk GenotypeGVCFs 
    --max-alternate-alleles 300 
    -R Zm-B73-REFERENCE-NAM-5.0.fa  
    -V gendb://mop1_db_chr1 
    -O mop1_variants_chr1.vcf
```

```
gatk SelectVariants 
    -R Zm-B73-REFERENCE-NAM-5.0.fa 
    -V mop1_variants_chr1.vcf 
    --select-type-to-include SNP 
    -O raw_mop1_SNPs_chr1.vcf
```

```
gatk VariantFiltration \
-R /fs/project/PMIU0157/Mahmood_Hasan/B73_ref_genomeV5/Zm-B73-REFERENCE-NAM-5.0.fa \
-V raw_wt_SNPs_chr6.vcf \
-O filtered_wt_SNPs_chr6.vcf \
--filter-name "QD2" \
--filter-expression "QD < 2.0" \
--filter-name "FS60" \
--filter-expression "FS > 60.0" \
--filter-name "MQ40" \
--filter-expression "MQ < 20.0" \
--filter-name "MQRankSum-12.5" \
--filter-expression "MQRankSum < -12.5" \
--filter-name "ReadPosRankSum-8" \
--filter-expression "ReadPosRankSum < -8.0"
```

#The output looks like the following

```
chr1    321     .       T       A       526.30  PASS    AC=10;AF=0.030;AN=336;DP=42;ExcessHet=0.0000;FS=0.000;InbreedingCoeff=0.3471;MLEAC=43;MLEAF=0.128;MQ=35.97;QD=25.36;SOR=0.892   GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL:PS
       0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,36  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,26  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,12  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,33  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,12  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,49  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,14  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,39  1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:321_T_A:90,6,0:321      0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,40  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,16  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,45  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,25  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,24  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,42  0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,41  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,40  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0
   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,15  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,11  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:321_T_A:90,6,0:321      0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,49  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,22  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:321_T_A:90,6,0:321      0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,20  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   1|1:0,2:2:6:1|1:321_T_A:90,6,0:321      0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   1|1:0,1:1:3:1|1:321_T_A:45,3,0:321      0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,14  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,26  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0
   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,39  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:2,0:2:6:.:.:0,6,49  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:1,0:1:3:.:.:0,3,16  0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0   0/0:0,0:0:0:.:.:0,0,0
```